# How do I get vitest to read my absolute imports?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, vite, vitest

I'm in the process of migrating from CRA to Vite, and I'm having issues trying to get my tests to work again.

My imports look something like this:

```
import { ComponentA } from 'components/ComponentA';
import { ComponentB } from 'components'; // has an index file

import { utilA } from 'utilities';

import { staticData } from 'components/staticData/data';
```

In my migration (and what I had previously with CRA), I've mimicked this absolute import setup from the CRA docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports

which I have set up with my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./@types"],
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "rootDirs": ["./bin"]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Notably, I'm following the `baseUrl` and the `include: ["src"]` fields from their documentation. I've also set up my `vite-config.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    server: {
      open: true,
    },
    plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths()],
  };
});
```

which works, and my app is building and rendering fine, however, when I try to run my tests with `vitest`, it gives me an `undefined` error for some of my imports. Here is the output:

[image: test output]

and where it's erroring:

```
import { ArelFilterInputTypes, IArelFilterColumnConfig } from 'components/filter';

console.log(ArelFilterInputTypes);
```

When I run a test, this shows as the output:

[image: console output]

#### What I've tried

I've initially tried to add `alias` and `paths` to my `vite-config` and `tsconfig.json`:

```json
// tsconfig
"paths": {
  "components/*": ["components/*"]
}
```

```
alias: {
  components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
},
```

But it doesn't work. I'm not entirely sure where the issue is with vitest. Could anyone help me?